# How to call a function which is inside another function's if statement

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement

I am trying to run this type of code:

Javascript Code:

```
var a = new XMLHttpRequest();
a.open('GET', 'text.txt');
a.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var a_text = a.responseText;
    If (a_text == "text I have written."){
        document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML= a_text;
        function z() {
            document.getElementById("elem2").setAttribute("class", "invisible");
        };
    } else {
        alert("Sorry, Text doesn't match.");
    };
};
  
function click() {
    z(); 
    //Some other codes 
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello</title>
        <style type="text/css" media="all">
            .invisible {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="elem"></p>
        <p id="elem2">Click the button to make me invisible.</p>
        <button onclick="click()">Click Me</button>
        <script src="javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

At the last I want that when I click on the button, `function click()` runs and `function z()` runs only if `a_text` matches required text. But even if the text matches, the console shows that **`z()` is not defined**.

Please include if you have any alternative code to do it easily.

Help me out please.

*This is a part of my code where I need the help. Solving this part will let me complete my project.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**z() is not defined.**

Because `z()` declared on inside the ajax callback not as a global.

And also not necessary do like this. You could do with declare as global function. And if you need any special behaviour with in function you could pass with params

**Updated**

```js
var a_text = '';

function z() {
  if(a_text == "text I have written.") {
    document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = a_text;
    document.getElementById("elem2").setAttribute("class", "invisible");
  } else {
    alert("Sorry, Text doesn't match.");
  }
};



var a = new XMLHttpRequest();
a.open('GET', 'text.txt');
a.onreadystatechange = function() {
  a_text = a.responseText;
}

function click() {
  z();
  //Some other codes 
}
```

Comment: Your code runs `z()` before I click on the button. But I need to run `z()` when I click on the button.

Comment: if you need only run on click event just remove the `z()` in ajax callback

Comment: That won't check the `a_text` to be matching or not

Comment: Please include if you have any alternative code for doing what I want.

Comment: @prasanth ! Hi Mate Typo `If`

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather oh ya.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you need to put `z()` declaration on the top level so that it can be called from `click()`.

Secondly, you have to create a flag `shouldRunZ` that will control whether `z` should run.

```js
function z() {
  document.getElementById("elem2").setAttribute("class", "invisible");
};
var shouldRunZ = false;

var a = new XMLHttpRequest();
a.open('GET', 'text.txt');
a.onreadystatechange = function() {
  var a_text = a.responseText;
  if (a_text == "text I have written.") {
    shouldRunZ = true;
    document.getElementById("elem").innerHTML = a_text;
  } else {
    shouldRunZ = false;
    alert("Sorry, Text doesn't match.");
  };
};

function click() {
  shuldRunZ && z();
  //Some other codes 
}
```